# Is this normal for a new soldering station?

Tags: soldering

I have just measured the temperature on my new Hakko FX-888D soldering station and I've noticed that the tip has become corroded/discolored even though I didn't use any solder at all. Should this be happening on a new station with a new tip?

Please see picture attached.

[image]

Comment: What was the highest temperature you measured or tried to achieve?

Comment: "*even though I didn't use any solder at all.*" This is why. You need to tin the tip and keep it tinned. Solder prevents oxidation. It doesn't cause it. Get a chisel or bevel tip. Conical is garbage.

Comment: High temperatures speed up oxidation so keep the tip's temperature as low as is practical. I generally use 325 degrees C. Only if I need to solder a large heat-absorbing item will I first heat up to 450 C, then solder, then turn down to 325 C again. And **always** keep solder on the tip. The solder also prevents oxidation.

Comment: What a relief to see decent equipment.  I was expecting another "the cheap tip on my cheap iron burned up" question.

Comment: @JRE I know, right? lol I'd be glad just to see it was a station. But man, the 888 used to be $100 ten years ago.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It was measured at the default temperature, which is 350 C (662 F).

Comment: @DKNguyen Medium sided conical tips (like OP's) are pretty pointless, but very fine conical tips do have legitimate uses, and when you need surgical precision you don't want a clumsy hoof on the end of your iron.  Depends what you're doing.

Comment: @J... Large and medium conical tips are indeed particularly useless. REALLY fine conical tips have a bit more use but you can get equally fine chisel tips so the conical almost never comes into play. My model of iron has a 0.6mm chisel as the smallest chisel and I have exactly one 0.3mm conical tip on hand for this reason, but I have never needed it. It still sits unused. Some other irons have chisels as small as 0.2mm and those irons have the smallest conical as 0.1mm. So for a given iron you can get smaller conicals than chisels but overall chisels can get so small you never need conicals.

Comment: If the tip won't take solder after that, you can use "tip tinner" to restore it. One small tin will probably last you for life. Also, you don't need to tighten the collar particularly tight when you change tips, just finger-tight - without using your fingers when it's hot, of course.

Answer (score 21):

Yes that looks normal, however you should immediately coat the tip with proper electronic grade solder as soon as it is hot enough to melt the solder and if  you wipe the tip, recoat it again. If you leave it for too long without solder it may become hard to "wet". Do not use acid core solder- it will damage everything including your circuits.

Also, do not set the temperature excessively high- follow the manufacturer's instructions for nominal settings.

Take care not to scrape or abrade the tip unnecessarily. The tip is coated with a thin plating of iron that is treated to "wet" on top of a copper base. If the iron layer is damaged then the copper core of the tip will rapidly corrode in the solder and you'll have to replace the tip.

Comment: Brass sponge is okay and generally doesn't count as abrading, and they're great.

Comment: @DKNguyen Other than the slight 'fingernails-on-blackboard' effect.

Comment: I am unaware of what you're referring to. I've not noticed marks.

Comment: @DKNguyen It's the sound.

Comment: Oh weird. I've not noticed that either. I just stab the sponge rather than wipe.

Comment: Even with frequent swipes on the brass sponge, our Hakko tips last for a long time (months and months).  Good stuff.  We're on year 5 or so of our FM206.  Ultra-reliable.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen Yes, I was more trying to dissuade OP from filing or sanding the tip as seems to happen from time to time, with disastrous results.  Similarly prying crimped leads up with the tip can damage it. Since brass is softer than iron (3 vs. 4.5 on Mohs scale) it's not inherently an issue and does not easily abrade the tip.

Comment: Just to be spell it out ,if the OP hasn't used a professional-quality iron before: there should be a holder for a piece of sponge which should be kept *wet* with water. Pressing the tip of the hot iron onto the sponge for a second or two *steam cleans* it without causing any mechanical damage from scraping or filing.

Comment: I've never used a brass "sponge" for this, but I would have thought the problem would be how to get rid of the solder that would end up "soldered onto the sponge". With a plastic sponge, you just scrape the sponge clean as required - and a piece cut from the cheapest bathroom sponge you can find in a supermarket works perfectly well. The water means the sponge itself never gets hot enough to burn.

Comment: I would say moist with water- there is a fine line between too dry (so the sponge may be damaged) and sopping wet. I have not tried supermarket sponges, only the professional Weller ones (they last a really long time).

Comment: @alephzero I've found wet sponges useless because it cools the solder too fast and then it solidifies on the tip. I also don't like the wiping action because I find it flicks up bits of solder everywhere. The brass wool has depth to contain all the solder, the sponge only has surface area so it last longer than you might think compared to a sponge of the same size. You basically hit a new part of the sponge every time you stab into it for a long time. Over time some parts of the brass wool does get harder and harder as the solder accumulates and stiffens it. Lasts at least a year.

Comment: @alephzero: Sponges should be **damp**.  If it sizzles, it is too wet.  You use the sponge to **wipe** the grunge off.  You do **not** "steam clean" the tip. That can cause cracks to develop in the surface of the tip.  Soak the sponge in water, then squeeze it out until you think it is dry.  It will still have enough moisture in it to keep the sponge flexible and protect it from burning.  Repeat when the sponge feels "stiff" while wiping the tip.

Comment: @alephzero Brass "sponge" doesn't get "soldered" so fast. If you give a couple of rapid "thrusts" in the sponge with the tip, the excess solder with all the dirt will get scraped away, but won't stick to the sponge. The solder (especially if dirty) will have no time to stick to the sponge and will form little "pearls" that fall through the sponge and end up on the bottom of the container. To make the solder stick to that sponge you really must have a large quantity of excess solder, high temperature and you must keep the tip in the sponge for a while.

Answer (score 8):

It's a common newbie mistake to always clean off the soldering iron tip before you put it back in the holder. That's the opposite of what you want to do. Keep a nice glob of solder on there when the iron isn't in your hand, as that will protect the tip from oxidation.

Clean the tip off right before you start soldering instead.

As others have said it's extremely important to cover a new tip with solder immediately once you heat it up. If that bare metal surface oxidizes too much the tip is basically toast.

Also, the hotter the tip the fast it will oxidize, so don't set it higher than you need it. For reference I solder exclusively lead free and use a tip temperature of 370C.

I personally also recommend shutting off the iron if you're not going to use it in the next 60 seconds or so.

Comment: I wouldn't shut if off. Just turn the temperature down to 100-150C maybe. Expensive stations will bring the temperature down automatically when in the holder, but not all the way to room temperature to reduce fatigue from thermal cycling and reduce warm up time

Comment: I don't think this particular Hakko model supports automatic shut-off. And it's an annoying feature anyway, because it takes too long for the tip to heat up again on Hakko irons (if you are used to Metcal). It does a big difference to tip ageing though.

Comment: Yeah it can be annoying to manually shut off your iron if it doesn't have auto-shut off but I'd still recommend it.

Answer (score 7):

Professional soldering irons are typically accompanied by printed notes that advise users to coat new tips immediately while warming, using high quality solder, and to keep coating and cleaning until the whole tip is covered.

The same advice applies whenever the tip became dirty.